# What is the difference of applying a CSS class/id directly to a tag vs wrapping the tag in DIV tags with the same class/id?

Tags: html, css

What is the difference of

```
<ol class="specialClass">
  <li>Hello World!</li>
</ol>
```

versus

```
<div class="specialClass">
  <ol>
    <li>Hello World!</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

I couldn't find an answer that explicitly answered this. I plan on experimenting and researching it further, but it'd be nice to get an answer to directly explain it (if possible) or a link to an explanation.

Comment: Is there something about it that you don't understand? Your question seems quite broad.

Comment: Ya, it is a fairly broad question that really just questions one of the fundamental semantics of html styling.I guess I'm really just wondering at the very least IF wrapping an element in a div of a class/id is DIFFERENT than just adding the class/id directly to the tag. But it'd also be nice to know how this translates to how the formatting is applied to the html element (if there is a difference). Also, thanks for the (quick) response :) I have a very strong feeling the answer will be the notorious (and often true) "it depends". In which case I'll just have to play with it more on my own.

Comment: As you surmised, it depends. In the code example you provided there's not much to note, but depending on the specific CSS, HTML, and any scripts there could be significant differences.

Answer (score -2):

If you put anything else under the div tag, the formatting will apply to everything before the end tag. Whereas, with the ordered list, the formatting only applies to the list text/blocks.